# how can i choose certain row from simulation using matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulation

I made a simulation in Matlab that outputs a matrix. So after 500 runs I'll have 500 matrices. How can I choose a certain row from those matrices? The row is `[xxx 1 0 0 0]`, where  `xxx` means the existing number that is different from one matrix to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ismember` for this

idxL = ismember(bigMatrix,[25,1,0,0],'rows');

`idxL` is a logical vector with ones wherever the row of `bigMatrix` equals the target row value, and zero otherwise. You can use this for indexing into other arrays. If you need row numbers, use `rowNumbers = find(idxL)`.